# Average distances between two point sets bound by polygon

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a table of boundary polygons, a table of points and a table of other_points

I want to work out the average distance between points contained within and other_points for each polygon.

So far I have this query which works but is not very efficient, I limit distances to within 10,000 meters (data is in SRID 27700). I am using POSTGIS to do this, I ultimately need to get the data into Postgresql.

I am sure it can be done better as this will take many hours to compute. Any ideas how?

```
WITH POINTS AS (

    SELECT  point_id,
            polygon_id,
            point_geometry as wkb_geometry 
   FROM boundary 
   LEFT JOIN points

  ), DISTANCES AS (

    SELECT 
        distinct ON (ogc_fid) ogc_fid,
        polygon_id,
        round(ST_Distance(B.wkb_geometry, D.wkb_geometry)::NUMERIC,1) as distance
    FROM
       POINTS B, other_points  D
    WHERE ST_DWithin(B.wkb_geometry, D.wkb_geometry,10000)
    ORDER BY ogc_fid,polygon_id,ST_Distance(B.wkb_geometry, D.wkb_geometry)

)
SELECT distinct polygon_id,
       count(polygon_id) over(partition by polygon_id),
       round(avg(distance) over(partition by polygon_id)::NUMERIC, 1),
       FROM DISTANCES
   WHERE DISTANCES IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Please use `alias.column` everywhere, having to guess what table comes from which table is no fun. For now all I can do is refer you to this answer: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/71607/16594 that contains the most important part you need to fix.

Answer (score 1):

OK so here is the much improved query thanks to the useful pointer given by Jakub

```
WITH POINTS AS (

    SELECT  point_id,
            polygon_id,
            point_geometry as wkb_geometry 
    FROM boundary 
    LEFT JOIN points

 ), DISTANCES AS (

      SELECT polygon_id, point_geometry <-> other_point_geometry as distance FROM
      (
        SELECT
              distinct on(point_id) point_id,
              polygon_id,
              point_geometry,
              (SELECT wkb_geometry FROM other_points ORDER BY wkb_geometry<->B.wkb_geometry LIMIT 1) AS other_point_geometry
        FROM points B
      ) AS FOO
 )
  SELECT distinct polygon_id,
         count(polygon_id) over(partition by polygon_id),
         round(avg(distance) over(partition by polygon_id)::NUMERIC, 1),
         FROM DISTANCES
         WHERE DISTANCES IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: You are still missing the `ON` clause of the `LEFT JOIN` between `boundary` and `points`.